# Uncaught TypeError: this.activeArray[i] is undefined

Tags: javascript, html, class, html5-canvas

I have been having a problem. I am trying to make Conway's Game of Life with javascript using one big class for the game. However, I get this error when I run my finished product despite using the function in the exact same way in another function. I declared the array here:

```
class Game {
 constructor() {
  this.cellSize = 5;
  this.aliveColor = "#FF756B";
  this.deadColor = "#181818";
  this.rows = Math.floor(canvas.height / this.cellSize);
  this.columns = Math.floor(canvas.width = this.cellSize);
  //Variables for two lifecycles, active and past iteration
  this.inactiveArray = [];
  this.activeArray = [];
```

And call on the array in these two methods:

```
    this.drawCells = () => {
  for (let i=0; i<this.rows; i++) {
    for (let j=0; j<this.columns; j++) {
      let color;
      if (this.activeArray[i][j] === 1) {
        color = this.aliveColor;
      } else {
        color = this.deadColor;
      }
      ctx.fillStyle = color;
      ctx.fillRect(i * this.cellSize, j * this.cellSize, this.cellSize, this.cellSize);
    }
  }
}

    this.arraysInit = () => {
  for(let i=0; i<this.rows; i++) {
    this.activeArray[i] = [];
    for(let j=0; j<this.columns; j++) {
      this.activeArray[i][j] = 0;
    }
  }
  this.inactiveArray = this.activeArray;
}
```

(Sorry for the bad indentation, this is my first post) The arraysInit function runs with no errors for sure as I have tried debugging all of it (to no prevail). An error is thrown in drawCells() on the line "if (this.activeArray[i][j] === 1) {" and I have no clue why, as I have clearly defined the array and used it.

Answer (score 0):

One thing I noticed, Cidom10, is that your line  `this.columns = Math.floor(canvas.width = this.cellSize);` has an = sign where it looks like it should be a division `/` sign. Not sure if that is just a typo or what.

But, I believe the real problem lies with the line `this.inactiveArray = this.activeArray;` which sets `this.inactiveArray` to be a **reference** to `this.activeArray`. It doesn't copy the array, which I believe you are trying to do with that line.

To copy the `activeArray`, you can use something like `Object.assign`:

```
this.inactiveArray = Object.assign([], this.activeArray);
```

My bet is that you are modifying `this.inactiveArray` at some point which is also modifying `this.activeArray` and causing some indexing issues and that's where those errors stem from.

Without more code to go off of, though, this is all in theory.

Comment: And I made a quick little JSFiddle illustrating how the **reference** line can affect your arrays: https://jsfiddle.net/h60tyv3a/